# mod_rewrite Regex Issue

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9])+$ http://<domain>/$1/ [L]
```

And when I got to the site and type:

```
http://<domain>/596
```

I am expecting it to redirect me to

```
http://<domain>/596/
```

However, it is redirecting me to:

```
http://<domain>/6/
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks! :-)
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The + needs to go inside the brackets.

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)$ http://<domain>/$1/ [L]
```

Otherwise what you are saying is I want one or more matches for a digit, rather than I want a single match with 1 or more digits.

Comment: Yikes. I should have seen that! :( Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @Eric Quite alright, I'm sure we've all been there plenty of times.